# How to get the surface in pygtk drawing area?

Tags: python, pygtk, pycairo

I want to save cairo drawing in pygtk to disk.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cairo
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

def draw(da, ctx):
    # ...
    
    # How to get the surface ?
    surface.write_to_png("image.png")


def main():
    win = Gtk.Window()
    
    da = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    win.add(da)
    da.connect('draw', draw)
    
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to get the **surface**? Or is there any better method to save the drawing to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

```py
surface = ctx.get_group_target()
```